# logic on XML using XSLT. (Conditions)

Tags: xml, xslt

```
    <Overall_All>
        <results>
            <class>Grade12A</class>
        </results>          
            <results>
            <class>Grade12B</class>         </results>
                        
        <results>
            <class>Grade12C</class>
        </results>
                <results>
            <class>Grade12D</class>
        </results>      
            <results>
            <class>Grade12E</class>
        </results>          
            <results>
            <class>Grade12F</class>
        </results>                      
        <results>
            <class>Grade12G</class>
        </results>
            <results>
            <class>Grade12H</class>
        </results>
        </Overall_All>
```

if results = Grade12A and result = Grade12B and result = Grade12C, Display "The class will be loggin online".

if results = Grade12D and result = Grade12E and result = Grade12F, Display "The class will be conducted at school".

if results = Grade12G and result = Grade12H, Display "The class will be conducted at next month".

my code is

```
<xsl:choose>
    


<xsl:when test="/*/school/results_feedback/result[position()>=1]='Grade12A' and ( /*/school/results_feedback/result[position()>=1]='Grade12B' and /*/school/results_feedback/result[position()>=1]='Grade12C') "> <p> The class will be loggin online </p> </when>

<xsl:when test="/*/school/results_feedback/result[position()>=1]='Grade12D and ( /*/school/results_feedback/result[position()>=1]='Grade12E and /*/school/results_feedback/result[position()>=1]='Grade12F') "> <p> The class will be conducted at school </p> </when>

<xsl:when test="/*/school/results_feedback/result[position()>=1]='Grade12G and /*/school/results_feedback/result[position()>=1]='Grade12H'"> <p> The class will be conducted at school </p> </when>
```

so the problem is when i run the code, the moment it finds Grade 12A in the loop, it ignores other scenarios,

```
<xsl:when test="/*/school/results_feedback/result[position()>=1]='Grade12A' "> <p> The class will be conducted at school </p> </when>...  
e.g <xsl:when test="/*/school/results_feedback/result[position()>=1]='Grade12A and /*/school/results_feedback/result[position()>=1]='Grade12C'"> <p> The class will be conducted on tutorials </p> </when>...
```

is there any logic to make them work in a loop so it doesn't ignore others and not display Grade12A only.

Comment: Considering the input you provided, what's your expected output?

Comment: my expected output is "The class will be conducted on tutorials".. currently its displaying The class will be loggin online first condition for Grade12A

Comment: Please properly format your question with an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63060034/edit) to it.

Comment: AFAICS, your conditions are not mutually exclusive. What should be the result if more than one condition is true?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your conditions correctly (which is not at all certain), you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Overall_All">
    <xsl:variable name="results" select="results/class" />
    <output>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$results='Grade12A' and $results='Grade12B' and $results='Grade12C'">The class will be loggin online</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$results='Grade12D' and $results='Grade12E' and $results='Grade12F'">The class will be conducted at school</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$results='Grade12G' and $results='Grade12H'">The class will be conducted at next month</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>Some other text</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Smooth: Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.

Comment: it does the same thing. it displays the first part only

Comment: @Smooth You did not answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060034/logic-on-xml-using-xslt-conditions/63060361?noredirect=1#comment111513714_63060034

Comment: Hey Michael, I also tried the same way. it only displays for Grade12A

Comment: @Smooth You did not answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060034/logic-on-xml-using-xslt-conditions/63060361?noredirect=1#comment111513714_63060034